# Is it possible to connect DB in Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA without third party JPA provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to connect a Oracle 12c DB and query a table and fetch the results.I am using Spring Boot 1.2.4.Now if I use Spring Data Jpa will it suffice this requirement or Do I need to use JPA provider like Hibernate or Open JPA is a must along with Spring Data JPA.

Is there any examples which use only Spring Data JPA without any third party JPA provider?

Comment: JPA is just a specification, so you need a provider to get it live. Spring Data JPA does not replace the providers, it is just a layer, doing some magic behind the scene, abstracting your code from the specific implementation, to make you easier work with any provider. But you still need to specify one.

Comment: @alfcope thanks for clarifying.So when defining JPA provider do we need to externally create LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and JpaTransactionManager in our app.Is there a way Spring Boot automatically create this beans if I provide its properties in YML or property file?

Comment: Spring Boot will automatically create the necessary beans. You have to provide the query string in the properties or yml file as well the dependency for your JDBC driver.